# MySQL new db and troubleshooting some connections to old DB still running

Tags: mysql

I just setup a new DB server replacing one that has been live for 5+ years. I normally set the db connections in the host file but now that the new server is up I still see some connections to the old server how can I track down where those connections are coming from?

Answer (score 1):

If you log into the old MySQL server and run the following:

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

You should see a list of all active connections, with the source host in the 3rd column. It should be of the form:

```
serverhost:12345
```

Where `serverhost` is the hostname you're looking for and `12345` is the source port. If you want to track down the process that's connecting to MySQL, on `serverhost` run the following:

```
serverhost# lsof -i :12345
```

You should get something like this:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
program 5954 root   27u  IPv4 -780315302       TCP serverhost:12345->mysqlserver:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
```

So in this example, command `program` at PID `5954` is the offender.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can view same informations explained by vmfarms also using Mysql Administrator (old gui) or Mysql WorkBench, into the section "Server Connections", after you login into the server as root.